# Ng2-smart-table Single Cell styling

Tags: ng2-smart-table

I wish to add custom coloring to a cell.

tried using

```
`styles: [`    
    :host /deep/ ng2-smart-table tbody > tr > td:first-child {
    color: red;
    }
    `]`
```

but this changes the color for the entire first column

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to color the first cell not only the first column you need to add `first-child` to `tr` as well:

```
:host /deep/ ng2-smart-table tbody > tr:first-child > td:first-child {
  color: red;
  }
```

Comment: how do I bind this style to a ngClass ?

Comment: You need to change `ng2-smart-table` to your class, for example: `:host /deep/ .testColor tbody`